# Python coinflip invalid syntax print help me pls

Tags: python, printing, syntax, invalidation

So I'm basically thying to do like a coinflip script and it gives me 'invalid syntax'at the last print.Could you please help me?

```
import random
print('Choose a number between 1 and 0')
answer=input()
number=random.choice('10')
random.choice('10')
print(random.choice('10'))
if answer == (number
              print("You won"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if answer == (number
              print("You won"))
```

should be

```
if answer == number:
    print("You won")
```